How can filter the sub-arrays inside an array?
This is my array.
I want to get the sub-arrays where the first element is "admin".
const array = [["admin", 1234], ["user", 999], ["admin", 5555]];

The expected output should look like this:
[admin,1234], [admin,5555]


We can use the filter method to check if the value of the first index of the subarray is "admin."
Here is the proposed solution:
const array = [["admin", 1234], ["user", 999], ["admin", 5555]];
const filteredArray = array.filter(subArr => subArr[0] == "admin");

console.log(filteredArray , ' <<---------- filteredArray');

Additionally, if the subarray is unordered
then we can look for the value "admin" and filter out the subarray.
const array = [["admin", 1234], ["user", 999], ["admin", 5555]];
const filteredArray = array.filter(subArr => (subArr.includes("admin") === true);


You can just use the filter() function. In the callback function you can use destructuring to get the first element of the sub-array, and compare that element to the value "admin":


const array = [["admin", 1234], ["user", 999], ["admin", 5555]];

const result = array.filter(([k]) => k === 'admin');

console.log(result);



